# jq: how to loop through sub arrays

Tags: json, jq

I'm having the following dataset:

```
{
  "data": {
    "activeFindings": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "findingId": "someFindingID#84209",
          "products": [
            "hostA.corp.somedomain.org",
            "hostB.corp.somedomain.org"
          ],
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 6
        },
        {
          "findingId": "someFindingID#2145016",
          "products": [
            "hostC.corp.somedomain.org"
          ],
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 1
        },
        {
          "findingId": "someFindingID#67129",
          "products": [
            "hostD.corp.somedomain.org"
          ],
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 4
        },
        {
          "findingId": "someFindingID#67774",
          "products": [
            "hostA.corp.somedomain.org"
          ],
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The following command (though the first result returns null) will give the list of **findingID** and its associated host(s):

```
cat test | jq -r '.data[] | .. | "\(.findingId?) \(.products?)"'
null null
someFindingID#84209 ["hostA.corp.somedomain.org","hostB.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#2145016 ["hostC.corp.somedomain.org","hostE.corp.somedomain.org","hostG.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#67129 ["hostD.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#67774 ["hostA.corp.somedomain.org"]
```

What I'd like to achieve is to loop through each values and pass the **findingId** & **products** as arguments in a bash script.

The following:

```
someFindingID#84209 ["hostA.corp.somedomain.org","hostB.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#2145016 ["hostC.corp.somedomain.org","hostE.corp.somedomain.org","hostG.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#67129 ["hostD.corp.somedomain.org"]
someFindingID#67774 ["hostA.corp.somedomain.org"]
```

Would result in:

```
./somescript.sh someFindingID#84209 hostA.corp.somedomain.org
./somescript.sh someFindingID#84209 hostB.corp.somedomain.org
./somescript.sh someFindingID#2145016 hostC.corp.somedomain.org
./somescript.sh someFindingID#2145016 hostE.corp.somedomain.org
./somescript.sh someFindingID#2145016 hostG.corp.somedomain.org
./somescript.sh someFindingID#67129 hostD.corp.somedomain.org
[...]
```

Any help/guidance on how to achieve the above would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```sh
jq -r '
   .data[][][] |
   .products[] as $product |
   @sh "./somescript.sh \( .findingId ) \( $product )"
'
```

---

First of all, `.data[] | ..` returns way too many nodes.

- `.data[][][]` would work great here.
- `.data.activeFindings.findings[]` can used if you want to be more precise.

---

You ask how to loop, but you're already doing it: `[]` is used to loop over an array.

The catch is that you want to loop without changing the context (`.`). To do that, we can use `as`:

```
.products[] as $product
```

---

Finally, we want to avoid [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs, so we'll use `@sh "..."`. In the string literal that follows `@sh`, all interpolated values are converted into proper shell string literals.

```
$ jq -rn '"foo bar" | @sh "cmd \( . )"'
cmd 'foo bar'
```

---

All together, we get the following program:

```
.data[][][] |
.products[] as $product |
@sh "./somescript.sh \( .findingId ) \( $product )"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uaW7FM78-D) on jqplay

Comment: It is working perfectly, thank you for your detailed answer and your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
jq -r '.data[]
| .. 
| objects
| select(has("findingId"))
| "./somescript.sh \"\(.findingId)\" " + .products[]
'
```

You might also want to quote the "product" values as well.
Or consider using `@sh`.